# Block process to wait future complete

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
String longMehtod() async{
    await longProcess()
    return ok;
}

Future<String> a = longMehtod()
//add some code to block the process to wait Future complete and I can get the value of a
```

Can I block the process and make sure the value must be print without use await/async?

or is there any method like blockingget in Rxjava?

Comment: I have add some code. I hope it make my question more clear

Comment: You can wait by this code `Future<String> a = await longMehtod();`

Comment: @mezoni, `await` does not return a `Future`, it's `String a = await longMethod();`

Comment: @RuiPires, Oh yes, this is my oversight. This is because I use `var` or  `final`, instead of constantly worrying about what type of data in the total will be obtained in the calculation process. I do not like to write unnecessary code, which, moreover, is a bad programming style. I mean a direct indication of the type of `lvalue` obtained from `rvalue`.